# computing skewness for multiple dataframes within a list in R

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, lapply

I have a list of 12 data frames (**my.list**). they all look the same. I want to calculate the skewness of the **nefah" column ** (the fifth column) for all of my data frames that in my list. I know how to compute the skewness separately for each data frame. 
I use the "moments" package:

```
library(moments)

skewness(X2016_kvish_1_10t, na.rm =  T) # compute 1 dataframe
```

so my question is, how can I compute the skewness of the fifth column in all my data frames within the list. 
I tried with loops but I don't know how to built it.

this is an example of my dataframe.

```html
    kvish keta maslul yom nefah                date day_mean day_min day_max
1       1   10      1   1  1710 2016-09-11 00:00:00 2848.375     588    4614
2       1   10      1   1   934 2016-09-11 01:00:00       NA      NA      NA
3       1   10      1   1   800 2016-09-11 02:00:00       NA      NA      NA
4       1   10      1   1   637 2016-09-11 03:00:00       NA      NA      NA
5       1   10      1   1   588 2016-09-11 04:00:00       NA      NA      NA
6       1   10      1   1   951 2016-09-11 05:00:00       NA      NA      NA
7       1   10      1   1  2312 2016-09-11 06:00:00       NA      NA      NA
8       1   10      1   1  3769 2016-09-11 07:00:00       NA      NA      NA
9       1   10      1   1  3348 2016-09-11 08:00:00       NA      NA      NA
10      1   10      1   1  2788 2016-09-11 09:00:00       NA      NA      NA
11      1   10      1   1  2879 2016-09-11 10:00:00       NA      NA      NA
12      1   10      1   1  3318 2016-09-11 11:00:00       NA      NA      NA
13      1   10      1   1  3713 2016-09-11 12:00:00       NA      NA      NA
14      1   10      1   1  4102 2016-09-11 13:00:00       NA      NA      NA
15      1   10      1   1  4333 2016-09-11 14:00:00       NA      NA      NA
16      1   10      1   1  4583 2016-09-11 15:00:00       NA      NA      NA
17      1   10      1   1  4614 2016-09-11 16:00:00       NA      NA      NA
18      1   10      1   1  4367 2016-09-11 17:00:00       NA      NA      NA
19      1   10      1   1  4040 2016-09-11 18:00:00       NA      NA      NA
20      1   10      1   1  3766 2016-09-11 19:00:00       NA      NA      NA
21      1   10      1   1  3443 2016-09-11 20:00:00       NA      NA      NA
22      1   10      1   1  2793 2016-09-11 21:00:00       NA      NA      NA
23      1   10      1   1  2439 2016-09-11 22:00:00       NA      NA      NA
24      1   10      1   1  2134 2016-09-11 23:00:00       NA      NA      NA
25      1   10      1   2  1317 2016-09-12 00:00:00 2818.042     660    4497
26      1   10      1   2   759 2016-09-12 01:00:00       NA      NA      NA
27      1   10      1   2   727 2016-09-12 02:00:00       NA      NA      NA
...
168 roes total
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lapply to loop through your list. You can specify that you want your function only to apply to the 5th column within the function argument of lapply.

An example:

```
# sample data.
my_list = list(data.frame(matrix(runif(100,1,10),20,5)),data.frame(matrix(runif(100,1,10),20,5)),data.frame(matrix(runif(100,1,10),20,5)))

library(moments)
lapply(my_list, function(x) {skewness(x[,5]) })
```

Which returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] 123.9227

[[2]]
[1] 107.6823

[[3]]
[1] 121.1198
```